# How to use wxPython Demos

Tags: wxpython

I am a new comer of Python. And recently, I am leanring Python GUI, I have downloaded wxPython demos from website, I can run these demos well in the demo floder, but when I copy this one demo I want to use singly to another floder, it runs wrong, just the dos flash away, so what the problem is?
  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The demo code has some wrapper stuff underneath that makes running the demos by themselves a little tricky. Fortunately, it doesn't take much to make it work. Most of the time, you just need to copy out the code and remove the logging information. I wrote a wiki page on the process here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, but I am sorry that I don't run this sample you gave in your answer correctly follow your instructions strictly. My email address is xinbinero@gmail.com, could you send me the py file of this sample to me? Thanks!